# How to set checkbox priority?

Tags: javascript

A common checkbox is available here. **.bucret**

If these two ids are selected, the value will be printed. **.bucret** + **.engelli**

```
$(".engelli, .bucret").click(function () {
let isBox2Checked = $('.engelli input').is(':checked');
let isBox3Checked = $('.bucret input').is(':checked');

if (isBox2Checked && isBox3Checked) {
    $('#textbox2').attr('value', '1.800,00');
} else {
    $('#textbox2').attr('value', '');
}
```

If the **.bucret** checkbox alone is checked, this value is written.

```
      $('.bucret').change(function() {
        if ($('.bucret input').is(':checked')) {
            $('#textbox2').attr('value', '1.950,08');
        } else {
            $('#textbox2').attr('value', '');
        }
    });

});
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work that way. First, I select **.engelli** id, then the **.bucret** id is selected and the value is written as 1.950.08.

Comment: JavaScript is not Java.  They are two completely different languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue occurs because you have two different event listeners that do their own thing. The last one firing is the one that wins. Why not combine your logic in one listener?

I'd advice to use the `change` event instead of `click`. Write an extra `else if` statement to see if *only* `.bucret` is checked or not.

```
$(".engelli, .bucret").on('change', function () {
  let isBox2Checked = $('.engelli input').is(':checked');
  let isBox3Checked = $('.bucret input').is(':checked');

  if (isBox2Checked && isBox3Checked) {
    $('#textbox2').attr('value', '1.800,00');
  } else if (isBox3Checked) {
    $('#textbox2').attr('value', '1.950,08');
  } else {
    $('#textbox2').attr('value', '');
  }
});
```